# Serializing ECJ GP Individual for later execution

Tags: java, serialization, genetic-programming

Using Genetic Programming with [ECJ 21](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/), I'm looking for suggestions on how to serialize a `ec.Individual` (after successful(?) evolution).

The trick is, I then need to deserialize this GP at a later stage, and execute it...preferably outside of the ECJ framework (there seems to be a LOT of scaffolding involved in "executing" a GP while working in the ECJ framework, since that is actually aimed at EVOLVING the thing, not "running" it).

I have sorta something almost there with this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    File f = new File("./my.params");
        if (!f.exists() ) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException(f.getName() + " does NOT exist");
        }
        ParameterDatabase pd = new ParameterDatabase(f, new String []{f.getCanonicalPath()});

        Output output = ec.Evolve.buildOutput();

        EvolutionState evs = ec.Evolve.initialize(pd, 0,output);

        evs.run(EvolutionState.C_STARTED_FRESH);
        Individual [] individuals =  ((SimpleStatistics)evs.statistics).getBestSoFar();

        String bestIndividStr = "";
        for (Individual individual : individuals) {
            bestIndividStr = printToLog(evs, individual);
        }

        Species s = individuals[0].species;
        s = new GPSpecies();

        Individual gpInd = s.newIndividual(evs,  new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(bestIndividStr)));
}

private static String printToLog(EvolutionState evs, Individual individual) {
    String bestIndividStr;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(baos);
    individual.printIndividual(evs, pw);
    pw.append(System.lineSeparator());
    pw.close();
    bestIndividStr = baos.toString();
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Evolve.class).info("Best Dude: \n{}",bestIndividStr);
    return bestIndividStr;
}
```

Ok, some of the problems with this:

1. How do I now feed in some variables and evaluate the `gpInd`?
2. In this sample situation, I have the original Individual available,
   so I can get the Species reference from that (which is then used to
   create a new individual from the output of the original). In my real
   situation, I won't have that.

Writing my own parser and evaluation stack for the text output produced by `printIndividual(..)` shouldn't be THAT hard, but I would prefer not to do that if there is an easier (built-in) way.

PS: what I have so far was built based on [this tutorial](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/docs/tutorials/tutorial4/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. 
My solution was to create a XML representation of the individual by subclassing `GPNode`. The following source shows the appropriate implementation.

```
public abstract class XMLGPNode extends GPNode {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2732707537997825895L;


public StringBuilder makeXMLTree() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        makeXMLTree(doc, null);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;

        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);
        sb.append(new String(sw.getBuffer()));
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return sb;
}


private void makeXMLTree(Document doc, Element parent)  {

    Element child = doc.createElement(toString());              
    if (parent==null) {
        doc.appendChild(child);
    } else {
        parent.appendChild(child);
    }

    if (children.length > 0) {                  
        for(int x=0; x<children.length; x++)   {
            ((XMLGPNode)children[x]).makeXMLTree(doc, child);

        }
    }

}
```

The final individual can then be serializied within the problem in order to save or transfer it to another application or load it for a new evaluation.

Following code snippet shows the `makeXMLTree`-method call of the root node within the `evaluate`-method of the `GPProblem` implementation.

```
    public void evaluate(final EvolutionState state, 
        final Individual ind, 
        final int subpopulation,
        final int threadnum)  {

    if (!ind.evaluated) {  // don't bother reevaluating

        int hits = 0;
        ...
        ...

        transformationType = new TransformationType(TransformationType.TYPE.values()[state.random[threadnum].nextInt(TransformationType.MAX_INPUT_TYPES)]);

        ((GPIndividual)ind).trees[0].child.eval(state,threadnum,input,stack,((GPIndividual)ind),this);

        XMLGPNode child = (XMLGPNode)((GPIndividual)ind).trees[0].child;


        **String individual = child.makeXMLTree().toString();**
```

...
...

Comment: Thanks @Diversity , it looks like a good solution. What I ended up doing was to basically write out an individual using `printIndividual(...)`, and then built my own parser for that, independent of ECJ (I had to be able to eval/execute the individual OUTSIDE of ECJ at later stages). Should be almost trivial to do for the XML output also (both ends up with tree structures).